# Amusing display bug when hovering over tags in a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

If you repeatedly slide your mouse back and forth over the tags listed for a question (that is, toggling their hover status many times), the user box slides farther and farther to the right, stretching the question frame (as seen by the bottom border) and causing the box to go under the right-hand sidebar and eventually off the screen, causing horizontal scrollbars (ew).

Happens both main and meta. I am using Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on a Windows 7 computer.

Comment: I got a related but different bug today on Safari/OSX, where it does the jiggle but doesn't progressively widen the box.

Comment: Wait, actually: I *do* get the progressive widening if I do it *enough* in a row. It gives me about a dozen or so jiggles before it starts pushing the usercard sideways.

Comment: As a non-mod who can't edit tags, I do not get this bug.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, that seems to match the behavior I’m seeing.

Comment: @GreySage That makes sense, it seems to be related to the appearance/disappearance of the edit tags button.

Comment: @GreySage It seems to be attached to the hover-over button for the “editing tags inline” power, which yeah, is only enabled if one has the [10k+ reputation privileges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). (You're well on your way!)

Comment: And another funny thing: it doesn't work on my so-old-it's-not-supported-anymore Firefox. Somebody created a bug which requires you to update your browser to see!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Meta SE, reproduced, explained, and fixed here: [User card senses danger when chasing tricky "edit tags", runs for dear life](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296193/153219).

Turns out it was a weird JavaScript/jQuery/CSS interaction bug.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the loveliest bugs I've ever had the pleasure of reproducing.

[image]

Go, little KRyan user banner! Go, be free!

[image]

Wait, he came back! ... He's showing SevenSidedDie's user info the way out! Go, little ones! You can do it!

Comment: Yeah, it really is quite fun, I like it a lot.

Comment: “[feature-request] Make Usercard Launching a configurable user option ([it is a vital part of my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/)).”